# Is it possible to make this function on numpy array more efficient?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, performance

Here `a` is a 1D array of integer indices. To give some context, `a` is the atom indices of the 1st molecules. The return is the atom indices for `n` identical molecules, each of which contains `step` atoms. This function basically applies the same atom selection to many molecules

```
def f(a, step, n):
    a.shape=1,-1
    got = np.repeat(a, n, axis=0)
    blocks = np.arange(0, n*step, step)
    blocks.shape = n, -1
    return got + blocks
```

For example

```
In [52]: f(np.array([1,3,4]), 10, 4)
Out[52]:
array([[ 1,  3,  4],
       [11, 13, 14],
       [21, 23, 24],
       [31, 33, 34]])
```

Comment: How big is your array in practice (ie. shape)? The current solution seems quite fine for a Numpy code.

Comment: it's not big, ~100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like broadcasting should be enough:

```
def f(a, step, n):
    return a + np.arange(0, n*step, step)[:, None]

f(np.array([1,3,4]), 10, 4)
```

output:

```
array([[ 1,  3,  4],
       [11, 13, 14],
       [21, 23, 24],
       [31, 33, 34]])
```

Comment: I was going for: `return a + (np.arange(n) * step)[:,None]`

Comment: @Quang it looks like it's similar in terms of timing. I naively thought using directly the correct step in `arange` would be faster.